# Как создать кнопку, которая при клике будет менять фон на определённую картинку?

Tags: php, html, css

Есть код на php,мне нужно,чтобы при клике на кнопку, картинка основного фона менялась на другую конкретную картинку.

```
echo("<button class='new'> ");
echo ( " <a href=\"$i.png\",>Просмотр</a> ");
echo ( " </button> " );
echo("</div>");
```

Comment: Никто не знает?

Comment: Это решается с помощью Javascript и CSS. В интернете можно найти тысячи примеров.

Comment: Не нашёл ни одного для кнопки

Answer (score 3):

```html
<button style="width:300px;height:100px;" onClick="this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/w3css.gif)';"> button text </button>
```